# Wikipedia SQL dump not loadable with Python/SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-2.7

I am using the sqlite3 library of python to process a Wikipedia .sql data dump, and I get the following "syntax error" report:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: categorylinks
```

Below are the steps I have taken to import the .sql into my database

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('wikicategories.db')
infile = open('enwiki-latest-categorylinks.sql')
str = infile.read()
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(str)
```

and the beginning of the .sql file looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `categorylinks` (
  `cl_from` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cl_to` varbinary(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cl_sortkey` varbinary(230) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cl_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `cl_sortkey_prefix` varbinary(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cl_collation` varbinary(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cl_type` enum('page','subcat','file') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'page',
  UNIQUE KEY `cl_from` (`cl_from`,`cl_to`),
  KEY `cl_timestamp` (`cl_to`,`cl_timestamp`),
  KEY `cl_collation` (`cl_collation`),
  KEY `cl_sortkey` (`cl_to`,`cl_type`,`cl_sortkey`,`cl_from`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=binary;
```

I really didn't see any problem with the `int(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT` part. And this file is released by wikipedia hence should be ready to use. I know that the Python `sqlite3` has a slightly different implementation w.r.t MySQL. Does it have something to do with this?

Comment: It's s **q** lite3. Anyway I'm not sure that sqlite supports unsigned integers. At least searching for "signed" or "unsigned" in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) does not yield results.
Reading [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) there is only one mention of unsigned, but it is actually ignored.

Comment: Thist `ENGINE=InnoDB` looks like MySQL to me. Are you sure this SQL works in SQLite?

Comment: “I know that the Python sqlite3 has a slightly different implementation w.r.t MySQL” — SQLite has a different implementation than MySQL period, regardless of Python. SQLite != MYSQL, nor is it made by the same people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not [SQL as understood by SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html). Loading it with `sqlite3` produces an error.

```
% sqlite3 < enwiki-latest-categorylinks.sql
Error: near line 1: near "unsigned": syntax error
```

This has nothing to do with Python.

You have two options:

1. Import the SQL file with MySQL.
2. Convert it to SQL that SQLite can understand.